# Error when trying to open list : SyntaxError: unexpected character after line continuation character

Tags: list, python-2.6

I'm very new to code and am trying to write a script to open another list. I keep getting the error

> SyntaxError: unexpected character after line continuation character.

```
with open(Users/Laura/Desktop/Diss/gene\ list.xlsx) as list_file:
for line in list_file:
    if line.strip():
        keywords.add(line.strip())
```

would anyone be able to tell me what I have done wrong?

Comment: Your [file names needs quotes](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html#reading-and-writing-files). (And the space does not need escaping.)

Comment: If i add quotes the file name isn't recognised.- also what do you mean by the space does not need escaping?

Answer (score 0):

I see three problems in your first line: one syntactical and two logical.

1. the `open` function expects a *string*. So you need to add single or double quotes around the file name. Not using them means Python interprets the first 'word' as a variable name, and after that it kinda goes "...?" because the rest of that line then makes no sense.
2. Python requires escaping of certain 'special' characters in a string, either to *make* them special (`\n` translates to a literal newline character) or to *remove* their special status (`\\` inserts just a single backslash, not two -- this is necessary because the single `\` character itself is a special character). When escaping any other character, the `\` is not silently removed -- it stays in the string. However, that means you are literally looking for a *file name* with those backslashes in them. And you don't have that file.
3. You are apparently working on a linux-like machine and trying to get access to one of your local files. But because you do not start the path name at the root of your file system, it expects you have a folder `Users` *inside* your current folder (and then `Laura` inside that, and so on). You need to either add a single slash at the start, so the full (*absolute*) path is correct, or remove the part `Users/Laura/` and end up with a *relative* path.

The relative path must assume your current working directory is in fact `/Users/Laura`. If it's not, you can make Python look it up for you :)

```
import os
from os.path import expanduser

home = expanduser("~")
print (home)
```

should show something like

```
/Users/Laura
```

Now you got your own "home" directory, you can use

```
with open(home+"/Desktop/Diss/gene list.xlsx") as list_file:
```

and it does not matter anymore from which directory you start your program (and with the added bonus that it will also work for other users).